# RelativeLayout and accessebility support

Tags: java, android, user-interface, accessibility

I am adding [accessebility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/accessibility.html) support to some application. It works fine with standart UI elements (buttons for example), but for some reason does not work with my custom element, wich is RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView (it looks like icon). I've defined android:focusable="true" and set contentDescription.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:contentDescription=”my content description”
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
    ...
    />

    <TextView
    ...
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could someone please list here all posible causes?

UPDATE:
Is there some way to know what layouts are on the screen at the moment and what order do they have (some layouts are transparent)?

Comment: +1 for asking something interesting and new thing.

Comment: Probably some needed method was ovverriden. There are a lot of custom elements and other bicycles in this code :( I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hierarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) for understanding where is your invisible views.

Answer (score 0):

The android docs have a section about designing for accessibility, is [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/accessibility.html#CustomViews) any use to you?